# Windows Server 2012 R2 Primary Domain Controller locks old computername

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

Before updating to 2012, old DC-name was: SERVER1

Now Primary-DC name is: SERVER2
SERVER1 was added to computer as DNS-CNAME-alias

Then we installed secondary DC: SERVER3
and tried switch SERVER1-name to that by updating DNS-CNAME-alias.

Currently PING-command works,  \\[IP], \\SERVER2 and \\SERVER3 works
Problem: \\SERVER1 -disk shares **only** work, when name is linked to SERVER2

Error-messages when SERVER1 is linked to SERVER3:
`- You do not have permission to access \\SERVER1. Contact your network administrator to request access.`
`- \\SERVER1 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.`

With Remote Desktop:
`- The connection cannot be completed because the remote computer that was reached is not the one you specified.`

Connection to \\SERVER1 does work with **some**  computers,
and it seems to work if I use login `COMPUTER\USER1` instead of `DOMAIN\USER1` (same password, naturally).

So it seems, that "AD has somehow identified SERVER1 as name of SERVER2",
and it suspects DNS-spoofing etc., when SERVER3 is connected.

We have quite a lot links to SERVER1, so I would appreciate any ideas how to fix this. 
(Oh, and SERVER2 is unreliable at the moment - which was reason for SERVER3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that (one) problem was with Kerberos SPN.
The solution was found from page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2706695

Elevated command, which seemed to fix the \\SERVER1 -shares was:
`setspn -A cifs/SERVER1 SERVER3`

Remote Desktop still does not work, but that is not really an issue.